# How to replace the node value in xml and save the output in same xml using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, minidom

I used minidom function to change the nodeValue in xml. But my code only changes the node value in buffer (when i print the xml , i get it with new value), i want to save the new node value to the original file. how is it possible? Pls help!

This is my minidom code:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse('test.xml')
nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("abc")[0].getElementsByTagName("mythread")
for key in range(len(nodelist)):
    if key == 2:
        nodelist[key].firstChild.nodeValue = 111
```

Here is my xml:

```
 <abc>
 <mythread name="newthread">99</mythread>
 <mythread name="ramptime">16</mythread>
 </abc>
```

I need to change/replace newthread value from 99 to 111 & save the value in the original file where it is located.